# Lag-free filter methods for time series

Tags: r, time-series, moving-average, filter

I'm currently working with accelerometer based raw data (100 hz). Now I want to low pass filter this timeseries of accelerations for further analyses.
I tried different filters like the simple moving average (SMA) or the exponential moving average (EMA) filter. But both methods produce lag, which I want to avoid. Are there any lag-free filter methods available for my kind of data? I'm doing my analysis in R, so appropriate R packages are prefered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filters like the [Savitzky-Golay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter) filter might just be what you are searching for. The core difference to classic `runmean` or `runmed` filters is that they fit itself to the signal in the running window, so don't produce the same lag as runmean or runmed would do (in case of this filter this is done using polynoms with convolution - so besides the window width, you have an additional filter order parameter to tune here). Here's a short example using a Savitzky-Golay filter in `R` with the `signal` package:

```
library(signal)
matplot(data.frame( beaver1[,3], 
                runmed(beaver1[,3], k = 11),
                filter(filt = sgolay(p = 5, n = 11), x = beaver1[,3])
                ), type='l', lwd=2, lty=1, ylab='')
legend('topleft', legend=c('original', 'runmed', 'Savitzky–Golay'), col=1:3, lty=1:3, lwd=2)
```

Comment: The filter capability looks great so far. Any hints on how to tune the filter? Is it better to enlarge the window size or to reduce the polynomial order, when I want more smoothing?

Comment: This will depend on which information you want to remain in the data (and what the noise you have looks like). With accelerometer data you can likely use domain specific knowledge for thinking about this (e.g. body movements: range of maybe 20Hz might be useful; with known sampling rate you might estimate some useful window length from this). And, after applying such a filter, you can easily look at the data again and check that this actually is what you would *want* to it to be.

Comment: Does this filter work offline or online?

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to run the filter once in the forward direction, then again in the reverse direction, which cancels the lag. The functions in [Python](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html) and [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/filtfilt.html) are both called `filtfilt()`. I'm not an R user, but there seems to be an R implementation [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/signal/signal.pdf) (also called `filtfilt()`). This could be useful if you want to design a filter with specific frequency response characteristics. Otherwise, smoothing methods (e.g. Savitzky Golay as geekoverdose mentioned, or LOESS, etc.) could be simpler.

Comment: Using a combination of a forward AND a reverse filter would allow me to use any kind of filter that suffers from lag right? Maybe I should look deeper into the characteristics of available filter methods.

Comment: @Robomatix Yes, `filtfilt()` will eliminate the lag. Note that the filtering operation is happening twice. So, if your filter were a simple smoothing kernel (e.g. a Gaussian window function), you'd be doubly smoothing. A well-defined lowpass filter (e.g. designed w/ R's `signal` toolbox) would be more typical with this approach.